# How do OTC Pink securities to move into the Grey Market?

Tags: stock-markets, penny-stocks, pink-sheets, over-the-counter

(Note: I'm new to the market mechanisms of the OTC market)

On any given day, there are usually securities that leave the OTC Pink market and fall into the Grey Market. For example:

> Fri, Jul 03, 2020 12:00 - Eos Petro, Inc. (EOPT: Grey Market) - Tier Change - The symbol, EOPT, no longer is classified as Pink No Information. As of Fri, Jul 03, 2020, EOPT resides in the Grey Market tier.
>
> Wed, Jul 01, 2020 12:00 - Consorteum Holdings, Inc. (CSRH: Grey Market) - Venue Change - The symbol, CSRH, no longer trades on OTC Link. As of Wed, Jul 01, 2020, CSRH trades on Grey Market.
>
> Wed, Jul 01, 2020 12:00 - Santa Fe Gold Corp. (SFEG: Grey Market) - Venue Change - The symbol, SFEG, no longer trades on OTC Link. As of Wed, Jul 01, 2020, SFEG trades on Grey Market.

According to OTC Markets' [glossary](https://www.otcmarkets.com/glossary):

> Grey Market, "OTC" or "Other OTC" is a security that is not currently traded on the OTCQX, OTCQB or Pink markets. Broker-dealers are not willing or able to publicly quote OTC securities because of a lack of investor interest, company information availability or regulatory compliance.

According to the definition above, the underlying reason for the move into the Grey Market is because of "lack of investor interest, company information availability or regulatory compliance". Given that the OTC Pink tier itself also has lots of securities that suffer from "lack of investor interest, company information availability or regulatory compliance", I would assume that broker-dealers tolerate this "lack of investor interest, company information availability or regulatory compliance" for quite some time before actually pulling the plug. My questions are:

- What actually happens to make OTC Pink securities fall into the Grey Market? Who actually decides that a company should, effective immediately, move out of OTC Pink and into the Grey Market? Is there some kind of formal mechanism to cause securities to move into the Grey Market?
- Why do some OTC Pink No Information securities manage to stay in the OTC Pink tier without falling into the Grey Market despite years of withholding company information?

Comment: Investopedia: [Gray Market](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/graymarket.asp)

Comment: Information from Charles Schwab: [OTC Securities](https://help.streetsmart.schwab.com/edge/1.62/Content/OTC%20Securities.htm)